# How can I make my icon stay in the center of my accordion header?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I have an accordion.
At the right of my accordion, I have an icon, and I want to set that icon to stay in the **center** of my panel-header.

As you can see right now, it's kind of too close to the bottom.

I've tried using padding, and margin, but so far I got no luck. I'm not sure whether or not I used them the wrong way.

---

## HTML

```
<div class="row sk-p">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">

            PRE-REQUISITE(S) FOR ALL SKILLS IN EXERCISE

            <span  data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#sk-p-r" class="hide-details-sk-p pull-right">

              <span class="hide-details-txt-sk-p-r">HIDE DETAILS</span>
              <img width="20px" class="icon-sk-p-r" src="http://s4.postimg.org/jd95wuzd5/incorrect.png">
            </span>

          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="sk-p-r" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">


           <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
             <span>SOLVING EQUATIONS BY ADDITION OR SUBSTRACTION </span><br><br>
             <div class="sk-p-dash">
               <img width="20px" class="icon-sk-p-r" src="http://s8.postimg.org/n1o8p0tsx/review_video.png">
               <span>WATCH VIDEO</span><br><br>
               <img width="20px" class="icon-sk-p-r" src="http://s4.postimg.org/n8ugz0v49/review_pdf.png">
               <span>REVIEW LESSON</span>
             </div>

           </div>


           <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
             <span>GRAPHING INEQUALITIES IN ONE VARIABLE </span><br><br>
             <div class="sk-p-dash">
               <img width="20px" class="icon-sk-p-r" src="http://s8.postimg.org/n1o8p0tsx/review_video.png">
               <span>WATCH VIDEO</span><br><br>
               <img width="20px" class="icon-sk-p-r" src="http://s4.postimg.org/n8ugz0v49/review_pdf.png">
               <span>REVIEW LESSON</span>
             </div>

           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>

   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

## CSS

```
 .sk-p-dash{
   padding-left: 25px;

 }

 .panel {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}

.sk-p {
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.panel-title, .panel-body {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.hide-details-sk-p {
  font-size: 9px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.hide-details-txt-sk-p-r{
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.row{
    padding-top:100px;
}
```

---

If needed - [HERE is my Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/4s6mLy6b/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a negative top margin to your icon.

```
.hide-details-sk-p .icon-sk-p-r {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/crwxdfL7/)

Comment: This works great. May I ask how do you know `-5` is the magic number ? Did you kind of play around with it until they're look nice ?

Comment: Yes, I played around it :)

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use position relative to determine where the icon should be displayed:

```
.hide-details-sk-p .icon-sk-p-r {
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
    left: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want `position: absolute`, that work good also with longer titles:

```
.panel-title{
    padding-right: 100px;
}

.hide-details-sk-p {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 7px;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/4s6mLy6b/3/

Note: Resize the window to see how it work.